# Return matches that have at least one message

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, the `match` table keeps track of matches and the `message_log` table keeps track of conversations for a match. Right now I'm getting all the matches by the following query

```
SELECT * FROM match order by id DESC
```

But I want to modify it so that it would only return matches that have at least one message in the `message_log` and at least one message has `own_account` set to false.

my match table

```
CREATE TABLE public.match
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('match_id_seq'::regclass),
    match_id character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    birthdate timestamp with time zone,
    bio text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    my_id character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    username character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    account_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT match_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT match_match_id_key UNIQUE (match_id),
    CONSTRAINT matcch_account_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
        REFERENCES public.account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

my message_log table

```
CREATE TABLE public.message_log
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('message_log_id_seq'::regclass),
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    from_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    to_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    match_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    unix_timestamp bigint,
    own_account boolean,
    reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
    insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    account_id bigint,
    match_pk bigint,
    CONSTRAINT message_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT message_log_message_from_id_to_id_match_id_unix_timestamp_key UNIQUE (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp),
    CONSTRAINT message_log_account_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
        REFERENCES public.account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT message_log_match_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (match_pk)
        REFERENCES public.match (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently and concisely with an `EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM match
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM message_log
  WHERE match_pk = match.id
  AND own_account IS FALSE
)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Btw it's really confusing to have `match_id`, and `match_pk` in the `message_log` table. Normally, the convention of `_id` means you're referencing something else in a different table.

Also, in PostgreSQL we never use `character varying(x)` unless there is a spec that imposes `x` you should just be using `text`.

Comment: I created this years ago when I was not familiar with Postgres, that's why I'm using charvar, I will change them to text soon. I also agree that my referances are also confusing. I did not know about convention back when I created this.

Comment: I tested your query, but it returns 0 rows, I know it should return some as I have matches with others replying

Comment: @Arya if it returns 0 rows, that's all she wrote. There is no problem in the query. Perhaps `own_account` isn't set to false, and it's null? Shy of that there isn't much room for error on your part either. Create a test case.

Comment: I'm going to look into things. I'll get back to you

Comment: By the looks of it, I have stopped using match_pk, and using match_id instead. Time to delete the match_pk from my table. I did change the query to this https://pastebin.com/xEdViAkB and it's returning results. Looks correct to you?

Comment: Looks like I need to create a FK constraint too, since match_pk is no longer being used

Comment: @Arya That looks right, but keep in mind you don't want to join on a text type. That's slower. Instead, join on an int preferably, or a bigint if you must.